# React.js routing within a separate container area on a page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a web application that uses ReactJS to handle client side navigation between the pages on the Nav bar. What I want to do next is set up an area of one of these pages in order that it can perform its own navigation and routing that is local to it's own area. Think of this page area as a kind of container for a game type app. My question is what would be the best approach for this? a) have all the navigation within that container handled by manual manipulation of id selectors or b) somehow leverage ReactJS routing just for this enclosed area.

If the answer is (b) I'd appreciate some guidance from all you ReactJS/front end gurus out there who don't mind helping a newbie out.

I've attached an image that hopefully depicts what I'm trying to achieve.
To reiterate: as the user clicks either left or right buttons the contents of the 'content frame' are changed accordingly. My question is if this is a valid use case for react router or would I be better off doing this by manual  component rendering?
[Page navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPCTB.png)

Cheers

Comment: iframe? 7 more tyo go

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Ok I wasn't aware of the <iframe> tag. Would that approach lend itself well for a medium scale app that has lots of page navigation going on. As I said I can imagine all sorts of manual ways to construct this but if there was a client side libs like React that already manages this sort of thing I'd love to hear about it.